# I have a JSFiddle that includes HTML, JavaScript, and CSS. Is there a simple way to implement it into a Dreamweaver page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dreamweaver, jsfiddle

I have looked practically everywhere online and have done quite a bit of experimenting of my own, but can't seem to get the same result in Dreamweaver that is present in the [JSFiddle result](http://goo.gl/4gXFwy).

Is there a relatively simple way to make a webpage of a site that is identical to the **JSFiddle** result (and how is it possible to do that)?

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors? My guess is that you are not including jQuery lib

Comment: The Fiddle you posted uses jQuery. Make sure you've downloaded a local copy of it and include it in your HTML. The Fiddle doesn't show it in the markup, but on the left hand side it will show you which libraries were included.

Comment: What is the HTML of the page you tried to make work in dreamweaver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is that jsFiddle hides certain things that are required in order for the code to work, most importantly in this case is the reference to jquery, jsfiddle will put that in for you behind the scenes but if you take your code out of jsfiddle and don't reference jquery as I have then the code is useless. Also things like `<style>` tags around your css, although not need in jsfiddle, are needed when pasting the code into something like dreamweaver.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            #turtle img {
                display: block;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                var img = $('#turtle').html();
                for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    more(img);
                }
                $(window).on('scroll', function () {
                    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('#turtle').height() - $(this).height()) {
                        more(img);
                    }
                });

                function more(content) {
                    $('#turtle').append(content);
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="turtle">
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/9b/Rickastleyposter.jpg" alt="infinity-turtle" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: by the way..is this some weird stack overflow rick roll?

Comment: No, it is not a rick roll. Thank you for your help--I forgot to include references to jquery.